# Chrome background script to make a ajax post to localhost php

Tags: ajax, post, cross-domain, localhost

I spent hours searching for a solution.

I have a chrome extension with content script that needs to pass some data to a local web site (localhost/mywebsite/page.php).

I tried number of ways but it does not work.

Here is my code

background.js

```
$(function(){
function send_data_localhost (json_obj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://localhost/mywebsite/page.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: '{"some":"json"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(responseData);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.');
        }
    });

}   
});
```

page.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
echo var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

manifest.json

```
     ....
 "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/"
  ]
  ....
```

I've already gone through a number of stackoverflow.com threads but none of the solutions worked, or I could not implement them correctly.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Kind Regards,
K.